# Create file name using date and time

Tags: java, datetime, filenames

I hope you could help me, I'm trying to call in the date from another class and looks like "2011-03-09 06-57-40", I want to use this to create the file below but everytime I do when the output runs it creates a new file as it re-runs calling the dat(). I know what's going wrong I'm just not sure how to fix it, I want to permently writw to the same file. I hope this makes sense? :/

Thank you for any help in advance :)

```
    date d = new date();
    String  cdate = d.date();


    String f = h;

    try{
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(cdate + ".tsv", true)));
        out.print(f);
        out.print("\t");
        out.close();
    }catch (IOException e){
    }
```

Comment: could you clarify what exactly you want to do with the file? I have two ideas: store the date / filename that you used. Or you could just use only he date and not also the time which would probably be enough for a logfile or something similar. btw is this java? maybe add the programming lanuage as tag as well.

Comment: Hi sorry I was not very clear, this is using Java and I want to create a file named todays date and time so it is always unique then I want to write data into it. Does that help? Many thanks.

Comment: @James no, it does not.. could you please elaborate more on the question?

Comment: So you do want date and time to obtain a unique file that does not exist? In your question above you say that you want to keep writing to the same file. I am still not clear what your goal is. I am guessing you only need the date and not the time?

Comment: OK sorry, thanks for trying to help.
I want to create a file name with the name for example 

2011-03-09 06-57-40.tsv

the problem is everytime I send send something to be printed out to this file from another class

date d = new date();
    String  cdate = d.date();


gets called again and a new file is created with a revised time, this happens over and over again so you end up with the files like this

2011-03-09 06-57-40.tsv
2011-03-09 06-57-41.tsv
2011-03-09 06-57-42.tsv

Comment: ah this makes it clearer :) Why not just store the date or filename or filehandle in a class variable? when does the file/filename need to be changed?

Answer (score 45):

To create a file named the current date/time:

```
Date date = new Date() ;
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss") ;
File file = new File(dateFormat.format(date) + ".tsv") ;
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
out.write("Writing to file");
out.close();
```

Comment: What you should consider is that if you write multiple files in a loop then you will probably overwrite some files because the time will be equal.

Answer (score 25):

This one probably much easier. Only one line of a code to assign the name of the file as date and time.

```
String out = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh-mm-ss'.tsv'").format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 12):

I'll try and answer all the same. To obtain a date or time string in the most controlled manner possible use the following code

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
```

Look up http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html . It might help with understanding. You can also add hour/minute or what you need to the formatted String.

Another option might be to always set the "lower" fields like milliseconds, seconds, minutes in the Calendar to zero.

```
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
```

If you are retrieving your date from another class and cannot directly create a calendar you can also put the date into the calendar (note: for just formatting you don't need the calendar)

```
cal.setTime(date);
```

Maybe this helps getting more control of the created filename / file.

Answer (score 2):

It will be just a bit more efficient - only one SimpleDateFormat and Date object for each file, as well as no String concatenation.

```
private  final static String getDateTime()  
{  
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd_hh:mm:ss");  
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("PST"));  
    return df.format(new Date());  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class BELogs {

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BSELogs.class
            .getName()); 

             boolean makeDir = false;
             Date date = new Date();
             SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy") ;
             String curDate =dateFormat.format(date);
             FileHandler fh;     

               public BSELogs()  {

         try {  

             File file = new File("/home//Desktop/Logs "+curDate);
             makeDir = file.mkdir();
             fh = new FileHandler(file+"/MyLogFile.log "+curDate,true);  
             logger.addHandler(fh);
             // Set the logger level to produce logs at this level and above.
             logger.setLevel(Level.FINE);
             SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();  
             fh.setFormatter(formatter);  

          } catch (SecurityException ex) {  **strong text**
             ex.printStackTrace();  
          } catch (IOException e) {  
               e.printStackTrace();  
           }  

    logger.info("Data Log Genrated............"); 

      }
}
```