# generating a random file name in java

Tags: java, string

I have to generate a random file name in the format:

```
(Date time duration mob_no Type).wav
```

where Type is of String type. and other variables are as usual. All variables `Date`, `time`, `duration`, `mob_no`, `Type` are random.

I've tried this code, but it isn't working:

```
public ArrayList<String> randomFileName() throws ParseException {
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfSub; i++) {
        START_DATE.add(String.valueOf(theDay.getTime() - 360000000) + 
                       random.nextInt(9999900));
        DURATION.add(random.nextInt(9));
        A_NO.add(9000000000L + random.nextInt(999999999));
        B_NO.add(1000000000L + random.nextInt(999999999));
    }

    return fileName;
}
```

Comment: Hello, the best Stack Overflow questions show research effort. To start, you should make an [edit] to your post to explain what you've tried so far. Where is your code? Include that as well. This will satisfy the requirement for research effort and also gives the community a starting point to help you, ensures you get better answers, and ensures we don't tell you things you've already tried. Good luck! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242433/create-file-name-using-data-and-time

Comment: 'public ArrayList<String> randomFileName() throws ParseException{
         
         for (int i = 0; i < noOfSub; i++) {
            START_DATE.add(String.valueOf(theDay.getTime() -  360000000)+random.nextInt(9999900));
            DURATION.add(random.nextInt(9));
            A_NO.add(9000000000L + random.nextInt(999999999));
            B_NO.add(1000000000L + random.nextInt(999999999));
                  
        }
       
       return fileName;
    }'

Comment: You can see for yourself that it's better if you edit your code into your question. Then you can format it so people can actually read it.

Comment: Why would the date and time and duration segments be random? Surely you want them to hold real data and only have a random segment later in the name? And have you considered [File.createTempFile()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File)?

Answer (score 4):

```
String randomFileName() {
    return "8xR6reSeKgImxYl86muxnimEtA5Z.wav"; // chosen using random.org
}
```

Comment: Wise choice making that community wiki, and also pretty entertaining. ;)

Comment: [Seems to be related.](http://xkcd.com/221/)  +1 for making me laugh.

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking for a random name, you can choose to use the random function in JDK to generate the UUID for you - otherwise, generate the date time from calendar/joda and concatenate the strings (or perhaps use string buffers if possible and then convert to string).

Answer (score 0):

You can generate a new data time stamp using the `nextLong()` of the `Random` class. Then, you can use a `SimepleDateFormat` to format it to the desired format. Duration and mob_no are just another 2 numerical values to generate.