# How to create a file with a different name every time

Tags: java, printwriter

I am making a program which exports some text to a text file every time you click a button, i want it so that every time you clcik the button the text file has a new name so the text file doesn't get replaced every time. I've tried this code

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sdf + "Title", "UTF-8");
                writer.println("Test"");
                writer.println("Test"");
                writer.println("Test");
                writer.close();
```

But it didn't seem to work so is there any way to do it?

Comment: You're using [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) wrong.

Comment: When you read something about a library class; you shouldn't stop there! Meaning: yes, there is the SimpleDateFormat class; but the idea is not that you turn objects of that class into a string ... but that you take timestamp; and then you can use the formatter object to turn the timestamp into a string. So - take the time to study the Javadoc for the things you intend to use.

Comment: Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5242433/create-file-name-using-data-and-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(sdf.format(new Date()) + "Title", "UTF-8");
```

you should use like this.

sdf - String, always constant.

sdf.format(new Date()) - It will give unique value each time it will call.